# ¿Como resuelvo el subselect para que devuelva una retorne una sola columna?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Necesito devolver en mi consulta únicamente el `nombre` de los participantes que hayan participado en al menos 3 peliculas. Dejo el MER adjunto

Se que el subselect debería retornar solo una columna, pero necesito el ¨participaciones¨ para compararlo con el 2 y con eso tomar los nombres que necesito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select P.nombre from personas P where P.nombre in (
select P.nombre, count(I.codigoPelicula) as participaciones
from personas P,participantes A, participa I
where P.id = A.idPersona and A.idPersona = I.idParticipante
group by P.id
having participaciones > 2
order by participaciones desc);
```

Comment: Por que no das mas detalles y pones un ejemplo con datos pa entenderte mejor

Comment: @japv ahí quedo actualizado

Comment: Si P.id = A.idPersona y A.idPersona = I.idParticipante entonces la tabla A no tiene nada que hacer en este query. Y mas alla de eso, cual es el problema? que respuesta recibis? cual es la respuesta esperada? No veo ningun problema aca...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas una sub-consulta para esto, puedes utilizar una sentencia `select` para obtener solamente el nombre del conjunto de resultados que devuelve la consulta agrupada, por ejemplo:

```
select nombre 
  from (select P.id, P.nombre, count(I.codigoPelicula) as participaciones
          from personas P 
               inner join participantes A on P.id = A.idPersona
               inner join participa I on A.idPersona = I.idParticipante
         group by P.id, P.nombre
        having count(I.codigoPelicula) > 2
         --order by count(I.codigoPelicula) desc
       ) q1
;
```

Dicho esto:

- Te recomiendo utiliza la sintaxis de *join* explícitos, no hay razón para usar *joins implícitos* en el 2021, cuando la otra sintaxis es mucho más clara y tiene 30 años de existir.
- Evalúa siempre las tablas que incluyes en el query, tienes tablas que no son necesarias en el from, no las he querido quitar yo, pero no debieras incluirlas.

Comment: :) igual no entiendo la pregunta que hizo, y por eso tambien le deje un comentario.. en realidad tu respuesta es la misma consulta que tiene, pero me hace ruido que dice que necesita solo el campo nombre, cuando su consulta ya le devuelve eso... para mi, esta fallando en lo que esta preguntando...

Comment: Es la misma solo en parte, su confusión es justamente que está tratando de llegar al resultado usando una sub-consulta, cuando esta no es necesaria, lo explico en mi respuesta.

Comment: @jachguate el problema principal que tengo es que necesito devolver solo el nombre, sin el count que es lo que uso para elegirlos. Esta consulta me sirve pero me devuleve 3 columnas.

Comment: @timo, debieras dejar eso claro en la pregunta. De mi parte, he editado la respuesta para mostrarte como puedes hacerlo.